# Unable to scrape data to N page

Tags: python, pandas, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, python-requests

As i want to scrape GullAhmed Website, As my code work properly but the problem is that i am facing n page scraping error
the page01 url : https://www.gulahmedshop.com/unstitched-fabric?p=01&product_list_limit=48
and the page last url : https://www.gulahmedshop.com/unstitched-fabric?p=25&product_list_limit=48
but problem is that i can't able to extract 1162 items only page one data i got in csv file
Please help me

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import time

url = 'https://www.gulahmedshop.com/unstitched-fabric?p=01&product_list_limit=48'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
content = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'product-item-info')
#print (content)
suit =[]
for property in content:
    name= property.find('a', class_ = 'product-item-link').text.strip()
    #price1 = property.find('span', class_ = 'price-container price-final_price tax weee')
    
    try:
        p_price = property.find('div',class_ ='price-box price-final_price')
        p_span_price=p_price.find('span',class_='price-container price-final_price tax weee')
        N_product_price = p_span_price.find('span', {"class" : 'price'}).text.strip()
    except AttributeError:
        N_product_price = ''

   # print(N_product_price)

    try:
        p_price = property.find('div',class_ ='price-box price-final_price')
        p_span_price=p_price.find('span',class_='old-price')
        old_product_price = p_span_price.find('span', {"class" : 'price'}).text.strip()
    except AttributeError:
        old_product_price = ''
    print(old_product_price)


   # print(old_product_price)

    
    try:
        Offer= property.find('div', class_ = 'label-content').text.strip()
    except:
        Offer=''

    #print(Offer)
    #try:
        
     #   linkmain = property.find('div',class_ = 'cdz-product-top')
      #  links = linkmain.find('a',href=True)
    #except AttributeError:
     #   links= ''
    try:
        
        links = property.find('a',{'class': 'product-item-link'})['href']
    except:
        links = ''
###   print( name,price,links)
    image = property.find_all('img',{'class':'product-image-photo'},src=True)
    for i in image:
        if 'data:image' not in i['src']:
            images=i['src']
   # print(images)


    fabric={
                'productname':name,
                #'product_made':product_made,
                #'product_color':product_color,
                'Product_Sale_price': N_product_price,
                'Product_Old_Price':old_product_price,
                'Offer':Offer,
                'product_image': images,
                #'Datetime': current_date,
                #'Member_acess': Member_acess,
                'links': links,
                
    }
    suit.append(fabric)
print(len(suit))
    #print( '\n\t\t\t\tGullAhmedUnstitched Embroidered Suit','\nproductname',name,'\nproductprice',price,'\nproductlink',links,'\nimagelink', image)

df = pd.DataFrame(suit)
print(df.head())
print("sAVING")
df.to_csv('E:/unstitched-fabric.csv')
```

Answer (score 2):

You should just be able to enclose your logic in a loop which cycles through each page number. For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

suit = []

for page_number in range(1, 26):
    print(f"Getting Page {page_number}")
    
    url = f'https://www.gulahmedshop.com/unstitched-fabric?p={page_number:02}&product_list_limit=48'
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    content = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'product-item-info')
    #print (content)

    for property in content:
        name= property.find('a', class_ = 'product-item-link').text.strip()
        #price1 = property.find('span', class_ = 'price-container price-final_price tax weee')
        
        try:
            p_price = property.find('div',class_ ='price-box price-final_price')
            p_span_price=p_price.find('span',class_='price-container price-final_price tax weee')
            N_product_price = p_span_price.find('span', {"class" : 'price'}).text.strip()
        except AttributeError:
            N_product_price = ''

        try:
            p_price = property.find('div',class_ ='price-box price-final_price')
            p_span_price=p_price.find('span',class_='old-price')
            old_product_price = p_span_price.find('span', {"class" : 'price'}).text.strip()
        except AttributeError:
            old_product_price = ''
        
        try:
            Offer = property.find('div', class_ = 'label-content').text.strip()
        except:
            Offer = ''

         #   links= ''
        try:
            
            links = property.find('a',{'class': 'product-item-link'})['href']
        except:
            links = ''
        
        image = property.find_all('img',{'class':'product-image-photo'},src=True)
        
        for i in image:
            if 'data:image' not in i['src']:
                images = i['src']

        fabric = {
            'productname':name,
            #'product_made':product_made,
            #'product_color':product_color,
            'Product_Sale_price': N_product_price,
            'Product_Old_Price':old_product_price,
            'Offer':Offer,
            'product_image': images,
            #'Datetime': current_date,
            #'Member_acess': Member_acess,
            'links': links,
        }
        
        suit.append(fabric)

df = pd.DataFrame(suit)
df.to_csv('unstitched-fabric.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: You are welcome!  Don't forget to select the answer as the accepted solution